# Using Views to list nodes that have the same field value as current node

Tags: views

I have a content type with a field. I need to create a block that lists all the nodes with the same value for that field.

Doing this for related taxonomy terms is easy: *Contextual Filter > Taxonomy term ID > Taxonomy term ID from URL > Limit terms by vocabulary > Vocabulary*.

I cannot make to the contextual filter work for that field. Under all combinations I tried, either everything appears or nothing does.

Answer (score 1):

[Views Token Argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_argument_token) is the module you are looking for. It allows you to use Tokens in your contextual filters fixed values.

Here is what to do to have your View working:

1. Set a contextual filter on your field (let's say Publication with machine name "field_publication") and under the section "When the filter value is not available", select `Provide a default value` and choose `Token` from the select list. Now, you need to fill the Token textfield with the token name (e.g. [node:field_publication]). Save your filter.
   [image: Token contextual filter]
2. Add a second contextual filter on "Content: ID", select `Provide default value` and `Content ID from URL` and under the "More" section, check the `Exclude` box to have the view return all matching nodes but the current one. Save your filter and your view.
3. Set your block display and you're done.

PS: Maybe it is unrelated but when using this "Token" option, the View preview does not work anymore for me.